# Compare columns (per row) of two DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

first of all, I'm quite new to programming overall (< 2 Months), so I'm sorry if that's an '*simple, no need to ask for help, try it yourself until you get it done'* problem.

I have two data-frames with partially the same content (general overview of mobile-numbers including their cost centers in the company **and** monthly invoices with the affected mobile-numbers and their invoice amount).

I'd like to compare the content of the 'mobile-numbers' column of the *monthly invoices DF* to the content of the 'mobile-numbers' column of the *general overview DF* and if matching, assign the respective cost center to the mobile-number in the *monthly invoices DF*.

I'd love to share my code with you, but unfortunately I have absolutely zero clue how to solve that problem in any way.

Thanks

**Edit: I'm from germany, I tried my best to explain the problem in english. If there is anything I messed up (so u dont get it) just tell me :)**

[Example of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJQ34.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, from what you said you don't have a ready code, but could you at least insert an example of your dataframe and what result are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you :) Did it. (Basically: If a mobile-number which is in our general overview appears on the invoice, the matching cost-center should be "added" to the Invoice)

Comment: please add as text and format, not a screen shot. It would also be useful to see some examples of what your 2 dfs look like (again not screen shot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

program meets your needs, in the second dataframe I put the value '40' to demonstrate that the dataframes already filled will not be zeroed, the replacement will only occur if there is a similar value between the dataframes, if you want a better explanation about the program , comment below, and don't forget to vote and mark as solved, I also put some 'prints' for a better view, but in general they are not necessary

```py
import pandas as pd

general_df = pd.DataFrame({"mobile_number": [1234,3456,6545,4534,9874],
                           "cost_center": ['23F','67F','32W','42W','98W']})

invoice_df = pd.DataFrame({"mobile_number": [4534,5567,1234,4871,1298],
                           "invoice_amount": ['19,99E','19,99E','19,99E','19,99E','19,99E'],
                            "cost_center": ['','','','','40']})
print(f"""GENERAL OVERVIEW DF

{general_df}

________________________________________
INVOICE DF


{invoice_df}


_________________________________________
INVOICE RESULT
""")
def func(line):
    t = 0
    for x in range(0, len(general_df['mobile_number'])):
        t = general_df.loc[general_df['mobile_number'] == line[0]]
    if t.empty:
        return line[2]
    else:
        return t.values.tolist()[0][1]

invoice_df['cost_center'] = invoice_df.apply(func, axis = 1)

print(invoice_df)
```

Comment: Your code works fine with the example above. However, if I try to use it on the "real" data, nothing happens (it prints the invoice_df as if nothing happened).

I get the dataframe data from .csv files, may this be the problem ?

Comment: Well... I guess I was kinda blind. Just figured out that the mobile-numbers in "general_df" are dtype object, and the mobile-numbers in invoice_df are dtype int64.

Do you know any solution how to convert object into int64 ?

Comment: In the pandas documentation there is ```https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html?highlight=to_numeric ``` I would recommend a video but it is in Portuguese, but if you want see it ```https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKeM93NTKQM&list=PL3ZslI15yo2pfkf7EGNR14xTwe-wZ2bNX&index=20```

Comment: @Kev I found the solution ```general_df["COLUM"] = pd.to_numeric(general_df["COLUM"])``` convert the desired column before doing the desired operations, if this is the desired solution, I ask you to give an up vote in the comment, it would help a lot =)

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to upvote. 

Thanks for your solution ! I changed the dtype to int64, but unfortunately there's still no correct output.

Comment: what problem are you having? 
And what would be the correct output?, if the comment tab is not enough to show, create a new question with the link of this one in the desc, and put the link of the new question in this comment tab so that I can locate it